# Mysql Pivot table using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, pivot-table

I need to generate report like pivot table in codeigniter. It is working in mysql PHPmyadmin but when I use in codeigniter it shows sql syntax error.

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT sf.nc_name, sf.code, ', @sql, 'FROM sirform AS sf INNER JOIN rejection AS rb ON sf.id = rb.sir_id GROUP BY sf.nc_name'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rnaiplpqcms\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331
```

```html
 //Controller
 public function report(){
    $data['report'] = $this->user_model->report(); 
    $this->load->view("templates/header");
    $this->load->view("pivot_report",$data);
    $this->load->view("templates/footer");
  }
  
  //Model
  
   public function report(){
        $this->db->query("SET @sql = NULL");
        $this->db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(rb.model = ''',model,''', rb.quantity, NULL)) AS ',model)) INTO @sql FROM rejection");
        $this->db->query("SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT sf.nc_name, sf.code, ', @sql, 'FROM sirform AS sf INNER JOIN rejection AS rb ON sf.id = rb.sir_id GROUP BY sf.nc_name'");
          $this->db->query("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql");
        $this->db->query("EXECUTE stmt");
        $this->db->query("DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt");        
  
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
      }
   
   //View
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table1">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Code</th>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Quantity</th>
                 <th>Model</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
              <?php if(isset($report)) {
                foreach($report  as $reports){ ?>
               <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $reports['code']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $reports['name']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $reports['quantity']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $reports['model']; ?></td>// Model as header and quantity below it
                </tr>
                <?php }} ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

```html
<!--Expected Output-->
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <th>Code</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Model1</th><!--Model Column as header-->
  <th>Model2</th>
  <th>Model3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>xyz</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>456</td>
  <td>abc</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you convert the query to a stored procedure on mysql and execute the SP from codeigniter??

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I don't know stored procedure.Can you show me some example how to do pivot table in SP and then execute in codeigniter? @Javier Toscano

Comment: How about the above Code? is it solvable.. @Javier Toscano

Answer (score 0):

You did not closed parentheses of CONCAT method.

```
$this->db->query("SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT sf.nc_name, sf.code, ', @sql, 'FROM sirform AS sf INNER JOIN rejection AS rb ON sf.id = rb.sir_id GROUP BY sf.nc_name')");
```